# Delete Image: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp.net C#. I am saving image file in the folder and deleting it. When I am deleting it gives error "The process cannot access the file 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Admin\Temp\visible_Jul-13-2009_035606.png' because it is being used by another process"

Code:

```
fupAddImage.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Temp") + @"\" + tempFilename);
File.Delete(Server.MapPath("Temp") + @"\" + tempFilename);
```

Comment: Add specific info... how you are saving the image and then how you use to delete it. If you can post the part of your code here.

Comment: fupAddImage.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Temp") + @"\" + tempFilename); 
File.Delete(Server.MapPath("Temp") + @"\" + tempFilename);

Comment: May be asp.net process has not rights to delete files.

Answer (score 2):

How do you save the image? Have you made sure that you dispose all Image and `Stream` objects that are used for saving the image? Since both `Image` and `Stream` (and `StreamWriter`) implement `IDisposable` you should make sure to call `Dispose` (or set up using blocks when creating the objects) so that the file is properly closed when the image has been saved.

**Update**: One thing that you could try is to save the image data yourself, in order to gain more control over exactly how it is done:

```
private static void SaveFile(Stream input, string fileName)
{
    using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int bytesRead;
        do
        {
            bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        } while (bytesRead == buffer.Length);
    }
}

// Pass the uploaded file data to the above method like this:
SaveFile(fupAddImage.FileContent, Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("Temp"), tempFilename))
```

Comment: What was the downvote about? If there are any errors in my sample it would be great to know so it can be fixed...

Answer (score 1):

You need to post some code to know for sure, but the file is probably still open somewhere and thus your application hasn't released the file lock yet. Try closing any open streams and disposing of any file handles pointing to the object before you delete it.

**You may also need to wait for the OS to release the file after disposing of all handles pointing to it.**

I'm guessing the problem is the above. If you're creating a file and deleting it in the next line, the OS probably hasn't even flushed the file to disk yet, let alone released the file handle and the lock. Try giving some time between the write and delete and see if you can delete it again.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code upload and remove image or file

```
    public class UploadFileTools
{
    private string _path = string.Empty;
    private string _fileType = string.Empty;
    private string _filename = string.Empty;
    private IFormFile _file = null;

    public string path
    {
        get { return this._path; }
        set { this._path = value; }
    }
    public string FileType
    {
        get { return this._fileType; }
        set { this._fileType = value; }
    }
    public IFormFile file
    {
        get { return file; }
        set { this._file = value; }
    }
    public string Filename
    {
        get { return _filename; }
        set { _filename = value; }
    }

    public bool Upload()
    {
        try
        {
            string filePath = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", _path, _filename, _fileType);
       if (_file.Length > 0)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(_path))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    _file.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    return true;
                }
            }
             else
                throw new Exception("Error!!! The file has a problem");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error !!! Your file could not be uploaded"+ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveFile(string path = null)
    {
        try
        {

        string serverPath = path;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serverPath))
            serverPath = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", _path, _filename, _fileType);
        if (File.Exists(serverPath))
        {
            File.Delete(serverPath);
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

view model :

```
    public class SendFormViewModel
{
    public IFormFile myFile { get; set; }
}
```

Call in Controller

```
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult save(SendFormViewModel model)
    {
        string fileName = string.Empty;
        string extension = string.Empty;

        try
        {

            if (model.myFile != null && model.myFile.Length > 0)
            {
                var allowedExtensions = new[] { ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg" };
                extension = Path.GetExtension(model.myFile.FileName);
                if (allowedExtensions.Contains(extension.ToLower()) &&
                    model.myFile != null&& model.myFile.Length > 0)
                {
                    UploadFileTools _up = new UploadFileTools();
                    string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
                    string staticPath = "/img/";
                    string path = webRootPath + staticPath;
                    fileName = "myImg";
                    _up.FileType = extension;
                    _up.Filename = fileName;
                    _up.path = path;
                    _up.file = model.myFile;
                    _up.RemoveFile(webRootPath + "/img/myImg" + extension);
                    if (_up.Upload())
                    {
                        return Json("ok");
                    }
                }
            }
            return Json("ok");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try typing in:

> openfiles file_path_and_filename

in command prompt (cmd.exe) to find the reason.

and also ensure you have delete access.